# How to run the regression function (or any tool/built-in macro) in microsoft excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, interop, excel-addins

I would like to know how to run the regression function in microsoft excel using c#. Currently i am following this tutorial to automate regression in excel:

http://www.michaelcodes.net/2018/09/using-c-to-automate-linear-regression.html

Everything works fine, but the function that i am using (x1 in the tutorial as the variable):

```
myExcelInteropApplication.Run(@"Regress", sheet.Range($"$A$1:$A${rowCount}"),
                sheet.Range($"$B$1:$B${rowCount}"), false, true, Type.Missing, sheet.Range("$D$1"),
                true, false, false, false, Type.Missing, false);
```

Throws the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Dynamic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll
Cannot run the macro 'Regress'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I have checked that the data analysis tab is usable in excel and i can successfully execute the regression function within excel itself manually. The rest of the program can also open excel, insert into the cells and close it.

My hypotheses is that the macro im trying to call is misspelled or that something within excel is preventing me from calling the tool/macro.

I am having trouble finding a reference sheet or something recording the macro/tool names, so any example would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Instantiate a new class for the Interop Excel App
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
//If you want to see the Excel Application Open Up
oXL.Visible = true;
//Enter the Path that stores your Excel App -> Analysis Lib
oXL.RegisterXLL("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\Library\\Analysis\\ANALYS32.xll");
//Example : If Cell B5 to B9 contains your y-values:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range yValues = Linearity_Sheet.Range[Linearity_Sheet.Cells[5, 2], Linearity_Sheet.Cells[9, 2]];
//Example : If Cell A5 to A9 contains your x-values:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xValues = Linearity_Sheet.Range[Linearity_Sheet.Cells[5, 1], Linearity_Sheet.Cells[9, 1]];
//Run Data Analysis:
oXL.Run("REGRESS", yValues, xValues);
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the name of the .xlam file that has the macro you are trying to run. For what you are trying to do, I think it should be something like:

```
myExcelInteropApplication.Run("ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", sheet.Range($"$A$1:$A${rowCount}"),
                sheet.Range($"$B$1:$B${rowCount}"), false, true, Type.Missing, sheet.Range("$D$1"),
                true, false, false, false, Type.Missing, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Running macros is fine, but i still get the same error. Finding the file does not seem to be the issue here. It is finding the regression function. "Regress" might not be the correct name of the function. I think to solve this problem, i need to find a reference sheet of all the function names, but there is very little documentation of this available online. I also dont know if i can open the file in 'n code editor to attempt to find the function.